# Setting resource path in sapui5 with CDN and component

Tags: sapui5

I use the following statement in my bootstrap within index.html to load the Resouces form the official CDN source.

```
<script  
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.commons"
    src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax='complex'
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                    "sap.ui.whatever.app": "./" }'
    >
```

In my index.html the component is loaded.

```
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.localResources("resources");
            new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                   name : "sap.ui.whatever.app"
                }).placeAt("appContent");

        });
```

When loading the app with local sources (src="resources/sap-ui-core.js") it works perfectly. Only when using the CDN source, I get console errors telling that my views are not loaded:

> Failed to load
>   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/view/App.view.xml: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://myserver.com:8003' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I read in the API that SAPUI5 by default uses the resource root relative to the source path. I tried to set the resouce root via in the bootstrap:

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "sap.ui.whatever.app": "./" }'
```

or in the init function of my view and/or component

```
            sap.ui.localResources("resources");
```

without success! Additional remark: the problem only occurs when using the component. How can I tell SAPUI5 to use my local sources?

Additional information:
my Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

The error occurs when the first (root) view is loaded via manifest.json. The manifest.json however could be loaded vai the same call.

[image: Error in ajax call]
Error occurs in 
jquery.sap.global-dbg.js (line 1852)

Comment: You shouldn't use the official sap namespace (`sap.ui`) as part of your namespace. Try something like `co.abex.whatever.app`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Now I receive the following error indicating that the manifest.json can't be found. Failed to load https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/myNamespace/AppName/app/manifest.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myserver.com:8003' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: Update: After adjusting the namepace in component.extend, manifest.json, and the index.html (Bootstrap) but still receiveing the error that view can't be found in the resource base path.

Comment: I have updated my post with additional information about project structure and location where the error occurs.

Comment: Your folder structure is a little weird. See here, their webapp folder is your WebContent folder: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/00/3f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a/content.htm?no_cache=true

Comment: The problem has been resolved by debugging into 
getResourcePath (ui5loader-dbg.js:526)
Here you see the namespaces that have been registered and the resource root path for the ns.

Very helpful location to troubleshoot this problem:

[![Helpfull debug spot][1]][1]

When no namespace ("") is provided than it uses indeed the url of the CDN resourses.



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5pOB.png